# Unable to push changes to gitlab due to file size

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

The local repository has #3 branches: **main**, **dev**, **fix**. I opened a new branch to develop a new feature, branching off from **dev**. Let's call it **F1** for simplicity. Once F1 was created, I started developing and committed locally 4 times. When attempting to push remotely to the GitLab server, I received the following error:

```bash
> git push -u origin **F1**
remote: GitLab: You are attempting to check in one or more blobs which exceed the 100.0MiB limit:        
remote: 
remote: - ca6ed555e459936e7ef77058b41f4f2db2a33a26 (965 MiB)        
remote: - 16daf5cf3af682f8aee7e062c9e407c060e57695 (130 MiB)        
remote: To resolve this error, you must either reduce the size of the above blobs, or utilize LFS.        
remote: You may use "git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep $BLOB_ID" to see the file path.        
remote: Please refer to https://gitlab.com/help/user/free_push_limit and        
remote: https://gitlab.com/help/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings        
remote: for further information.        
To 'https://gitlab.com/**dire_name/repo_name**.git'
 ! [remote rejected]   **F1** -> **F1** (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/**dire_name/repo_name**.git'
```

It's undoubtedly an issue related to the size of the files I'm trying to push. Using the suggested command and inputting the illustrated IDs, I managed to understand that it depends on two TensorFlow libraries.

- `site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.2`
- `site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so.2`

To resolve this, I tried some suggestions:

- Utilize LFS. **It is enabled in my GitLab remote repository**
- Refer to https://gitlab.com/help/user/free_push_limit and https://gitlab.com/help/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings. **I do not find this section in my GitLab remote repository**

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need those large files in your repo? Point is, it is unusual to version build artifacts. Therefore, the simplest solution would be to remove them from the repository. You will need to use interactive rebasing to remove them from earlier commits then, but that should fix it.

Comment: I am already taking track of the libraries used. I do not need to add to my repository. Can you give me some more detail about interactive rebasing and then remove the `site-packages` from the repository? Of course, I would like to not lose any changes I made in the commits I mentioned before.